# Python: ValueError too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, grid-search, train-test-split

I am trying to find a best xgboost model through GridSearchCV and as a cross_validation I want to use an April target data. Here is the code:

```
    x_train.head()
```

[x_train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyhtI.png)

```
    y_train.head()
```

[y_train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMjGI.png)

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
    from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
    from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
    import xgboost as xg

    xgb_parameters={'max_depth':[3,5,7,9],'min_child_weight':[1,3,5]}
    xgb=xg.XGBRegressor(learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=100,max_depth=5, min_child_weight=1, gamma=0, subsample=0.8, colsample_bytree=0.8)
    model=GridSearchCV(n_jobs=2,estimator=xgb,param_grid=xgb_parameters,cv=train_test_split(x_train,y_train,test_size=len(y_train['2016-04':'2016-04']), random_state=42, shuffle=False),scoring=my_func)
    model.fit(x_train,y_train)
    model.grid_scores_
    model.best_params_
```

But I have this error while I am training my model.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtvQk.png)

Can anybody help me with this please? Or could someone suggest how can I split nonshuffled data to train/test to validate model on the last month?

Thanks for helping

Comment: `test_size=len(y_train['2016-04':'2016-04'])` check this part of the code..

Comment: @Ajay but whats wrong with this part I can't see..I just writing a length of the test_size here

Answer (score 6):

The root cause for this error is the way how you used `cv` parameter in the `GridSearchCV()` call:

```
cv=train_test_split(x_train,y_train,test_size=len(y_train['2016-04':'2016-04'])
```

Here is an excerpt from the docstring for the `cv` parameter:

```
cv : int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, optional
    Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy.
    Possible inputs for cv are:
      - None, to use the default 3-fold cross validation,
      - integer, to specify the number of folds in a `(Stratified)KFold`,
      - An object to be used as a cross-validation generator.
      - An iterable yielding train, test splits.

    For integer/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and ``y`` is
    either binary or multiclass, :class:`StratifiedKFold` is used. In all
    other cases, :class:`KFold` is used.

    Refer :ref:`User Guide <cross_validation>` for the various
    cross-validation strategies that can be used here.
```

However `train_test_split(x_train,y_train)` returns 4 arrays:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
```

this is causing: `ValueError too many values to unpack (expected 2)` error.

As a workaround you can specify one of the options specified above (docstring for the `cv` parameter)...